# Accessing the output of a union sub query in another

Tags: oracle

I have a very complex query (1000+ lines) that consist of 3 unions as follows:

```
select *
from (

    (... subquery expression with some ids) // unionquery1
    UNION
    (... another subquery expression with some ids) // unionquery2
    UNION
    (... another subquery expression with some ids) // unionquery3

)
```

The situation I've found myself in is the 3'rd union query is duplicating 3-5 ids which were already returned from the first 2 union queries. The only solution I could think about is in the restriction of the 3rd union query, do something like

```
where id not in (`copy over all the code from unionquery1`) and id not in (`copy over all the code from unionquery2`)
```

Is there a more graceful way of doing this?

In other words, the id's returned from unionquery1 and unionquery2 should not be duplicated in unionquery3. Could this be done in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the WITH clause to avoid having to repeat the subqueries multiple times:

```
with a as (
    select 'test1' as txt, 1 as id from dual
),
b as (
    select 'test2' as txt, 2 as id from dual
),
c as (
    select 'test3' as txt, 1 as id from dual union all
    select 'test3' as txt, 2 as id from dual union all
    select 'test3' as txt, 3 as id from dual
)
select * from a 
union all
select * from b where id not in (
    select id from a
)
union all
select * from c where id not in (
    select id from a union all select id from b
)
```

The Unions can now become Union All because we know the IDs will be distinct from the 3 separate parts of the union. A Union is more expensive than a Union All because it removes duplicates from the result set.

Comment: Thanks and apologies for my late response. I contracted COVID the day after I posted this and was out for 3 months

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with a help of CTEs and `not exists`?

```
with
q1 as (select id, whatever from some_table),
q2 as (select id, whatever from another_table),
q3 as (select id, whatever from third_table c
       where not exists (select null 
                         from q1 
                         where q1.id = c.id
                        )
         and not exists (select null
                         from q2
                         where q2.id = c.id
                        )
      )
select * from q1 union 
select * from q2 union 
select * from q3;
```